# How can I use NonlinearModelFit with multiple variables?

Tags: fitting, example

I am trying to find the coefficients for following equation:

$\quad \quad f(x,\,y,\,z) = a (x^2)\, exp(b x + y^2) + c z^2 y$

using `NonlinearModelFit`. But I can't find an example of how to formulate the data matrix and equation for `NonlinearModelFit` when there is more than one independent variable. Can someone provide an example?

Comment: If you mean to generate a matrix with this formula, you can try `Table`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: The first example in the "Scope" block of the NonlinearModelFit help page precisely shows the necessary steps. Took me less than 15 secs to find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I understand you're asking:

For your problem the data matrix has to be of the form {{x,y,z,f},{...},...}. I will create some data.

```
data = MapThread[{#1[[1]], #1[[2]], #1[[3]], 
          0.34*(#1[[1]]^2)*Exp[-1.82*#1[[1]] + #1[[2]]^2] + 
            0.94*(#1[[3]]^2)*#1[[2]] + #2} &,
  {RandomReal[1, {100, 3}], RandomReal[{-0.01, .01}, 100]}];
```

Then,

```
model = a*(x^2)*Exp[b*x + y^2] + c*(z^2)*y   
NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {a, b, c}, {x, y, z}]

(*FittedModel[0.385936 E^(-1.89747 x + y^2) x^2 + 0.943513 y z^2]*)
```

Answer (score 4):

To generate data using the given equation, you can use different values for `{a,b,c}` to generate data. Here's a method using `With` where `{a,b,c}` are local variables:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := With[{a = 0.1, b = -3., c = 1.2}, a *x^2 *Exp[b *x + y^2] + c* z^2* y];
```

Then you need to build you dataset; You can use `Table` and `Flatten` to have your data in suitable format (`{x,y,z,f[x,y,z]}`):

```
data = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, z, f[x, y, z]}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}], 
   2];
```

then using `NonLinearModelFit` is simple:

```
NonlinearModelFit[data, 
 a *x^2 *Exp[b *x + y^2] + c* z^2* y, {a, b, c}, {x, y, z}]
(* 0.1 *x^2 *Exp[-0.3 *x + y^2] + 1.2 * z^2 * y *)
```

therefore fitted values for `{a,b,c}` are the same as given in $f(x,y,z)$ definition.